# launcher animation when phone is unlocked

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-launcher

I'm new to Android and I'm trying to make a launcher as my first Android project. I've done the basic work of displaying installed apps. Now I want to add animations to improve user experience. But I'm not able to figure out the following two things :

1. How to add animation when the phone is just unlocked and apps are displayed on the homescreen like in iPhone or MIUI stock launcher?
2. How to know the app that is minimized or closed on pressing the home button so that I can show an animation like the app is minimized to it's icon on homescreen just like in MIUI?

Answer (score 0):

OnResume() of your application activity will be called once user presses home button or unlocks phone. So you can implement you logic of showing animation there.

Comment: This works fine when any app is minimized. But it's not working when phone is unlocked.

Comment: I think it will be called. Show you main activity code

Comment: @Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    overridePendingTransitions(R.anim.in, R.anim.out);
}

Comment: Try to put a break point and test. I tested with a sample app and call back is coming to onResume()